# IronPython cannot import module os

Tags: c#, .net, python, import, ironpython

So I have a basic ZIPPED IronPython (2.6 or 2.6.1) that I just unzip, start ipy.exe, type "import os" and hit enter.
The following output happens:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named os
```

It doesn't work even if I import clr first. What's it to be done ?

I've googled this issue but no relevant answer. The closest idea was this (which didn't work):

```
import clr
clr.AddReference("IronPython")
clr.AddReference("IronPython.Modules")
import os
```

Comment: Is the structure to the Libs directory still intact when you unzip? This is needed for it to find all the system libraries.

Comment: it is exactly like in the zip, and compared to CPython it's much smaller

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Likely, the problem is not the in zip, but in os module location.

You need to have `CPython` installed and your script should be able to reach the `CPython Lib` directory. To get this you can either copy all the os necessary files under your `Lib` directory, or you can set the environment variable `IRONPYTHONPATH` to point to the `Lib` directory below `CPython`.

Comment: but won't this conflict runtimes ? if any installed python library from Lib has C or C++ modules ?

Comment: Mmmh... I'm not sure, but probably some modules won't work if they depend on C or C++...

Comment: This worked for me. On OSX I did `export IRONPYTHONPATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/`

Answer (score 1):

This must help:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("C:\\PythonXY\\Lib")
```

Comment: Try to add more about why this will help.