# No module named optparse (IRON PYTHON)

Tags: .net, python, ironpython

when i add get_events_devices.py to the ironpython and import it at namespace it gave me error 
"No module named optparse" and take me to hilight that error in its code "get_events_devices.py" at this line (from optparse import OptionParser) 
   please help me out

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

[The latest version of `optparse` from 2.6.x](http://svn.python.org/view/python/branches/release26-maint/Lib/optparse.py?view=markup)

Comment: That one you're not getting around. You're going to have to port either `optparse` or `get_events_devices.py` to IronPython.

Comment: i have imported get_event_device.py when i get the error for which i did this post now when you told me to import optparse then my second post is the answer i want to import get_events_devices.py then how do i debug it ??? i havnt understand your post @ignacio -Mohsin

Comment: As a side note: If you are going to go through the trouble of porting, you should take a quick look and see if it would be the same effort to port over argparse, as it has some better-nicer features : http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html :

Comment: The reason for porting `optparse` isn't to parse command line arguments, it's to get get_events_devices.py working.

Comment: @syed: Ignacio said 'port', not 'import'. Porting means changing the code so that it runs. But I think he may be wrong -  see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3904374/ironpython-cannot-import-module-os